# Monitor azure service bus queue length

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

Team,

I would like to monitor a azure service bus dead letter queue length using normal C#. it should throw an exception when the receiver is not able/late  to process messages from the active queue and due to time delay the count in the dead letter queue increases.

Is there a way without using ApplicationInsights ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the "old" Service Bus SDK, you can get it from [`MessageCountDetails`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.messagecountdetails?view=azure-dotnet):

```cs
var msg = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);
var queue = msg.GetQueue(queueName);
var dlqCount = queue.MessageCountDetails.DeadLetterMessageCount;
```

Answer (score 1):

While using the full framework .NET client still provides message counts, according to the Azure Service Bus team the advised way is to use [Azure Monitor service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-overview-azure-monitor). The service has a .NET client that can be used to obtain the needed information ([example](https://weblogs.asp.net/sfeldman/reading-azure-service-bus-metrics)). Service Bus team has also published a sample [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/servicebus/2018/03/29/new-metrics-emitted/). The client has not provided all the information in the past, but that is work in progress and could be different now than before.

In case you're still planning to use Service Bus client to retrieve message counts, I highly advise to use .NET Standard client rather than full framework client. The "new" client doesn't have `NamespaceManager`, but it has an equivalent, `ManagementClient` that will provide the functionality you're looking for, including improvements over its predecessor and bug fixes moving forward. The "old" client is on a limited support only.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to fetch the Count of Messages(both active and dead-letter) in a Queue with the help of the latest [Azure Monitor Metrics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-supported-metrics?redirectedfrom=MSDN#microsoftservicebusnamespaces). Or you can make use of the [Azure Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-overview-azure-monitor) in Azure portal, which allows you to configure dashboards and alerts.